# How to obfuscate jar file by proguard in java 11

Tags: proguard

Hello everyone I am trying to obfuscate a jar file through proguard software 
but in the very first screen it showing error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yebxl.png)

Comment: Not sure but can you check path if JDK is actually installed at location.

Comment: Also which version of proguard are you using